# Chess problems: "Set play"

Tags: phrase-meaning

The fictive alterating to Black having the move, in a chess problem (where traditionally White moves first), is called "set play". I assume that's not because you are now allowed to play with the set (of figures) but because the play is set. In some sense. I got no answer on that on a problem chess board; maybe someone here knows definitely what the phrase means?

Addendum: Also, on a related note, if in the set play all Black moves can be answered to fulfil the stipulation, but White really has to search for a useful move, it's called, as a genre, "White to play" (as said, it's *always* White to play, so its tautological ;-)). Comments on the genesis of that phrase also are welcome.

Nitpick Note: In a helpmate Black begins. Usually.

Comment: fictive? alterate: do you mean alternate? [Don't you get a red line for alterate when you type it?] Sorry, in any case, I don't play chess so I can't answer the question.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, fictive means imaginary or made up. Maybe the OP means **Chess problems [studies / compositions] where black moves first (traditionally White moves first) are called "set play"** I must admit that in 70 odd years pf playing chess, I've never heard this name and googling it turns up nothing.

Comment: @PeterJennings I don't think fictive is the right word here.

Comment: @Lambie Agreed. Hauke, where did you find the phrase "fictive alterating". ?

Comment: In the handbook "Things that non-native speaker speak" :-) Sorry, I speak English since 50 years but I still don't do it right...

Comment: Hauke, no problem, that's what we are here for, to help. In English we have the difference between fictive (a rare word coming from fiction and fictional) which is used for things like plays and stories which are made up by the author, and chess problems / studies / compositions where the position is to demonstrate a point of play or act as a puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a technical term, and [its definition can be found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess_problems#:%7E:text=moves%20without%20reply.-,set%20play,-Play%20that%20is) in technical glossaries

> **set play**
>
> > Play that is possible from the initial position of a problem if the other player moves first. For example, in a directmate, set play consists of lines of play starting with a black move (rather than a white move). When set play exists, the key move may be something that does not change the set play lines, in which case the problem is a complete block, or the lines in the set play may change, in which case the problem is a mutate. Set play is one phase of play.

I think the phrase comes from the idea of black "setting up" for white. So in a directmate problem (one in which white has to checkmate black while black attempts to avoid mate) the set play is the move that black makes first.  And white has to find the checkmate move *whatever* black does in their move.